# Why does my sass not work now after is has been working for the past few days

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I started a react projects and everything was working fine. I then started working with sass and it was all working for a few days without any problems, now all of a sudden sass has completely stopped working but my react app is still working as it should just without all of the sass styles.

Is there a reason for this because I have been trying to figure this out for a few days and I cant seem to figure out what I have done or whats happening.

**If I use css it works fine**

```
package.json file:

{
  "name": "crwn-clothing",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "firebase": "^9.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.5",
    "sass-loader": "^12.1.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Install node-sass package for using sass with react

Comment: i have as i said it was working for a few days and now it is not working anymore

Comment: it stopped working automatically ?

Comment: I think so. i was just carrying on building the app and i noticed that all of my styles had disappeared

Comment: share your package.json file

Comment: i added it above

Comment: everything seems fine, why does it stopped working !!!

Comment: I have no idea.